# How to create a restricted directive?

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm experimenting with AngularJS and NG-Table and cannot solve the following:

I'm displaying a collection of User objects from a Django app in an NG-Table. One of the properties of the model is a boolean indicating whether the object is active. In stead of displating true/false, I want to display a glyph from the Font Awesome set using an AngularJS directive.

From various samples I've got the following.

The module:

```
var main = angular.module("main", ["ngTable"]);
```

Retrieval of the objects to be displayed in the table:

```
main.factory('User', function ($http) {
    return {
        async: function() {
            var promise = $http.get('api/v1/users').then(function (response) {
                return response.data["objects"];
            });
            // Return the promise to the controller
            return promise;
        }
    };
});
```

The controller and the directive to transform the boolean to the glyph:

```
main.controller("UsersCtrl", function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, User) {
    User.async().then(function(data) {
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 4,
            sorting: {
                name: 'asc'
            }
        },{
            total: data.length, // length of data
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                // use build-in angular filter
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        });
    });
}).directive('boolean', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var userObject = scope.userObject;
            if (userObject["active"]) {
                console.log("active");
                console.log(elem);
                elem.html = "<i class='fa fa-check text-success fa-lg'></i>";
            } else {
                console.log("not active");
                console.log(elem);
                elem.html = "<i class='fa fa-times text-danger fa-lg'></i>";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then in my HTML template:

```
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="propertyObject in $data">
            <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">
                [[ userObject.name ]]
            </td>
            <td>
                <boolean>[[ userObject.active ]]</boolean>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Due to collision with Django template conventions I had to change the Angular's default double curly brackets to square brackets.

The table displays ok, but for my `boolean directive` which fails to display a glyph and still just shows true or false. By logging to the console I can inspect the actual objects and they appear correct. I'm obviously missing something but would appreciate any help as to what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into issue where you need to let `ng-repeat` complete it's digest before trying to manipulate the element html. There are several ways to do it, using `attrs.$observe` or `$timeout`.

Baasically what is happening is your code is firing before the element is rendered

For no more than what you are doing you could simply use `ng-class` and you won't need a directive

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="propertyObject in $data">
        <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">
            [[ userObject.name ]]
        </td>
        <td>
            <i class='fa fa-times fa-lg' 
             ng-class="{'text-danger':!userObject.active,'text-success':userObject.active}">
            </i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or you could really simplify the directive to only return the `<i>` as `template` using the `ng-class`